# Loading packages Netezza R

Tags: r, netezza

I am using R on IBM's Netezza to process large amounts of data. We have been able to launch R and perform basic arithmetic using the core language. However, we are unable to use even the most basic packages including nza.

```
library(nza)
Error in library(nza) : there is no package called ‘nza’
```

Specifically, my question is how can I download basic packages in R using the Netezza and then point the R environment to wherever they have been downloaded to. Also if I could get directions for doing this from the terminal as opposed to the gui that would be best.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the package `nza` and where is it from? It is not a CRAN package or you would just have to download it by `install.packages("nza")`. It must be some third Party package that you can not expect us to know. It is most definitely not one of the most Basic packages in R.

Comment: Ok, I found it mentioned here: https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2010/abstracts/Biecek+Chudzian+Dendek+Lindsey.pdf Maybe you could contact the authors, if no better answer shows up here.

Comment: Bernhard, my question is not about installing R packages on a general purpose computer. The Netezza uses fpga's tuned specifically for processing large amounts of data. Consequently, R does not operate in the same manner. What I meant by 'basic packages' was packages required to do pretty much anything with netezza R. I apologize for my question not being clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is an old thread. But I installed nza recently. So sharing it. 
Please download the packages from this link and use "Install packages from Local Zip Files" to install them.

install.packages("C:.../Netezza_R_Installation_and_Client_R-3_v2/packageZips/nzr_3.0.2.zip", repos = NULL, type = "win.binary")

I believe you have options to set the library path.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/W4c715f465f89_464f_9fd9_b1d36a3c54f8/page/Installing%20Open%20R%20on%20PureData%20for%20Analytics%20(Netezza)

I tried this in R version 3.2.0.

It requires other packages. Please download the archived versions of the other packages from CRAN.

I reread your question. I am a developer and I don't have access to the Netezza box. So I am trying to connect to the box using Rstudio.